# Probability to pick 2 pairs of socks from 5 pairs when choosing 5 socks

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

My approach is as follows :

Probability of picking 5 socks from 10 socks = 10C5

Probability of choosing 2 socks from Sock group 1 = 5C2

Probability of choosing 2 socks from Sock group 1 = 5C2

We can choose in such = 5C2 * 5C2*6/10C5

Can you please elucidate what is wrong with my approach

Comment: Could you give some precision? Is it the probability to have exactly two pair, or to have at least two pair? This is not the same question (nor the same answer).

Answer (score 1):

As you say, there are $\binom{10}{5}$ ways of picking $5$ socks out of the $10$. On the other hand, there are 
$$\binom{5}{2}\cdot 6$$ 
ways of choosing $5$ socks making sure that you pick $2$ pairs: choose $2$ pairs out of the $5$ pairs, and then choose one of the remaining $6$ socks. So the probability is
$$ \frac{\binom{5}{2}\cdot 6}{\binom{10}{5}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming two socks in specific pair to be identical**,

**case 1**:number of ways of selecting 2 pairs and 1 other sock = (5,2)*(3,1) =30

**case 2**:number of ways of selecting 1 pair and 3 different socks=(5,1)*(4,3)=20

**case 3**:number of ways of selecting 5 different socks =(5,5)=1

```
      Required probability= 30/(30+20+1)
```